# Wrong Result Once I process try and catch

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

I wanted to check try and Catch in Java
my code

```
public class tester {

public static void main (String arg[]){

int[] hi = new int[3];
try{
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
hi[i] = i;
}
System.out.println(hi);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    System.out.println("wronnnnnng");

}

}
}
```

and it works without problem but once I change the array index to make it larger like 5
I should see from 0 to 4 but I just see random numbers?

```
public class tester {

public static void main (String arg[]){

int[] hi = new int[5];
try{
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
hi[i] = i;
}
System.out.println(hi);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    System.out.println("wronnnnnng");

}

}
}
```

and as result I got `[I@3343c8b3`? why?

Comment: Are you printing an `Object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fix your program to no longer throw an exception, it reaches the

```
System.out.println(hi);
```

line. However, since `int[]` array does not override `toString`, it calls the default `toString` of `java.Object`, which prints arbitrary numbers.

As a matter of exercise, consider writing a loop that prints these numbers. You could also use `Arrays.toString`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `System.out.println(hi);` where `hi` is an array. Java arrays do not override `toString()` from `Object` so you get a hashcode. You could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) like,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hi));
```

Answer (score 0):

`class name @ hex hashCode` is the [default `toString()` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) in Java. `[I` is the class name of an `int` array.

Use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) for a legible result:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hi));
```

This is how the class name of an array is represented: `"[" * array dimensions` + `component type`. ([more information here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2))

Comment: Could you elaborate on `class name @ hex hashCode`?

Comment: @nikpon If you look at the source of `toString()` in `Object`, you'll find this: `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. Arrays don't override this behavior, so it's what you see when you print an array.

Comment: What is a strange class name, why a class name of the array?

Comment: @nikpon It's just how types are represented internally by the JVM. This is the specific grammar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2 (look at table 4.2 also)

Comment: It's internal types, how to make an object using that type?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: If you have a class name, how to create an object of that class? Do you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is returning the reference or memory address of object `hi` which is an array. You should have to use `toString` mehtod of `Arrays` class because java `Arrays` doesn't override the `toString()` method of object class.

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hi));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
public class tester {

 public static void main (String arg[]){

  int[] hi = new int[5];
  try{
   for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    hi[i] = i;
    System.out.println(hi[i]);
   }
  }
  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   System.out.println("wronnnnnng");
  }
  System.out.println("goooood");
 }
}
```